# HashMap with an object later referred null and GC

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, hashmap

I have this confusion going on with HashMaps. If I have a HashMap let say HashMap.  Then I add keys and values to HashMap like this

```
HashMap.put(1,myObj1);
HashMap.put(2,myObj2);
HashMap.put(3,myObj3);
```

Now if I do myObj1=null, the value is still available in the HashMap the reason I believe (correct me If I am wrong) myObj1 only contains a pointer (reference) to the place in memory. So in the HashMap the reference that myObj1 had was copied. As myObj1 is now pointing nowhere (null) but the copied value in the hashMap is still pointing to the memory location. So now what kind of reference is this Weak, Strong. Will myObj1 garbage collected if so the value it was pointing to ( the value hasHashMap still points too), what happens to that.

Comment: The instance previously stored in the variable `myObj1` is still stored in the hashmap, so it will not be garbage collected. Things are garbage collected when there are no more references to them, which obviously doesn't apply to things stored inside a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in the HashMap implementation  always has strong reference.  What it means, unless you remove the element/map it won't be garbage  collected.  There is another implementation  in java called WeakHashMap which store the key as weak reference.  This key will be garbage  collected regardless its removed from Map or not. Please note the value in WeakHashMap  still has strong reference.

Answer (score 3):

Any Object is candidate to be garbage collected only **if no references** point to it.

If you do the following:

```
Object myObj1 = ....
myMap.put(1,myObj1);
myObj1 = null;
```

You have the internal references from `myMap` to that `myObj1`.
When you leave the references to the `myMap` if no other reference (explicit or implicit) to `myObj1` exists it become a candidate to be garbage collected.

So if you explicitly put to null the reference to `myMap` `myObj` become a candidate to gc.

```
Object myObj1 = ....
myMap.put(1,myObj1);
myObj1 = null;    // myObj1 is not candidate to be gc
...
myMap = null;     // myObj1 and myMap are candidates to be gc
```

Comment: Also if you remove the entry from the Map

Comment: Yes correct. If you remove the entry from the map, and no additional references to the object are present.